# Click event not working on angular universal app

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have a component with a function and a click event like this:

header.component.html:

```
        <button (click)="menu()"
                class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                aria-label="Main menu"
                aria-expanded="false">
```

header.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  url: string;
  isHome: boolean;
  showDropdown = false;
  menuItems = [
    {name: 'About Us', route: 'about-us', isOuter: true},
    {name: 'Technology', route: 'features', isOuter: false},
    {name: 'Mission', route: 'headline', isOuter: false},
    {name: 'Sign Up', route: 'contact', isOuter: false},
  ];

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isHome = this.router.url === '/';
    const url = 'url';
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      this.isHome = event[url] && (event[url] === '/' || event[url].includes('/#'));
      this.showDropdown = false;
    });
  }

  /** Mobile */

  menu(): any {
    this.showDropdown = ! this.showDropdown;
  }

  getMenuClass(): string {
    return this.showDropdown ? 'block' : 'hidden';
  }

  getMenuOpenClass(): string {
    return this.showDropdown ? 'block' : 'hidden';
  }

  getMenuClosedClass(): string {
    return this.showDropdown ? 'hidden' : 'block';
  }
}
```

I just installed angular universal for server side rendering and for some reason click event is not working and the function is not being triggered My `showDropdown` flag is working fine, I hardcoded it to `true` and it works.

Comment: So what do you need if everything goes well? I have tried your example and it goes both with true and  like this this.show = !this.show;

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work using angular universal. Click event is not triggered.

Comment: Hm I´m testing it on universal and its work, how is You html file?

Comment: What do you mean? its a lazy loaded component

Comment: but this component have something for show You menu

Comment: Yeah but thats not the point, it happens in any component I try click event...

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help you, I have tried your example and it works well for me.

Comment: have you managed to solve this? I have the same problem. Also other events are not firing as well.